# The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, mvc, azure

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Данная строка выходит, когда я пытаюсь запустить сайт azure с базой данных. Я склоняюсь к тому, что с базами данных какая-то путаница.

Я создал БД на Azure и наполнил ее через запросы. Скопировал строку подключения БД и вставил ее в код вместо локальной БД. Далее я опубликовал изменения и, собственно, вышла строка с ошибкой.

С чем это еще может быть связано или что не так со строкой подключения?

P.S. строки заменил следующие: DefaultConnection, а также в прописке репозитория сайта. Может нужно что-то прописать в mdfFilePath? Его я не трогал.

```
string mdfFilePath=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/GameStore.mdf");
context = new EFDbContext(string.Format(@"...", mdfFilePath));
```

Comment: При открытии какого именно адреса вы получаете ошибку?  Как именно вы запускает приложение?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы подключиться к бд вам нужно:

1. Создать сервер базы данных и саму базу данных в Azure.
2. Добавить ip адреса с которых будет происходить подключение к бд в белый список брандмауэра.
3. Взять строку подключения к интересующей вас бд. Вставить в нее имя и пароль пользователя.
4. Использовать получившуюся строку подключения.

Чтобы получить строку подключения выберите интересующую вас бд в списке ваших баз данных, затем найдите ссылку "Показать строки подключения к базам данных".
Ссылка на настройки брандмауэра находиться на той же странице.

Строка подключения будет иметь примерно следующий вид:

```
Server=tcp:{адрес сервера},{порт (по умолчанию 1433)};Initial Catalog={имя базы данных};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={имя пользователя бд};Password={пароль};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Эту строку подключения вы и должны передать в конструктор объекта DbContext
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделал как Вы описали, ничего, к сожалению, не изменилось.

Comment: Через обозреватель sql server в VS вы можете подключиться к вашей базе данных?